# Civilization V (from the steam client) freezes on 16.04

Tags: games, steam

I'm currently using ubuntu 16.04 on a lenovo thinkpad t460. I downloaded the steam client a few weeks back and have been using it to play civilisation v ever since. However, every so often (usually after having put laptop to sleep), the game screen completely freezes and I'm forced to force-quit, losing my progress in the process (strangely though, the mouse retains its in-game style and audio works perfectly fine).  What should I do?

Comment: Try to run it by terminal and post the error message when it freeze (if there is one). Do you play in fullscreen ? If so, try to play it in windowed mode.

Comment: I think the better recommendation is to save, either locally or at Steam Cloud, and exit the game before suspending. Suspending with a full screen game on was never a good idea.

Comment: @Aegefel Sorry, I am new to ubuntu. How exactly do I "run it by terminal"?

Comment: Open a terminal window (Alt-Ctrl-T) and run `steam`. When your game freezes, hopefully there will be error messages or debugging info displayed in the still-open terminal window.

Comment: @Nick No, the steam client itself runs fine. Only the game window freezes.